# Pointers to struct and cast

Tags: c, pointers

C language ensures that a pointer to any `struct` may be converted to `void *` and vice versa. Also, the language permits to define pointers to a `struct` also if it's undefined. I would assume that, since the compiler doesn't know anything about these structures, their pointers should have the same physical representation. Let's consider these lines into two separate modules:

```
/* FILE1.c */
void *mem = ...; //Points to a suitable memory block
struct s1 *p1; //No implementation given for struct s1
void *mem2;

p1 = (struct s1 *)mem;
mem2 = &p1;


/* FILE2.c */
extern void *mem2;
struct s2 { /*...fields...*/ };
struct s2 *p2;

p2 = *(struct s2 **)mem2;
```

Is this code able to work on all the platforms, provided that the memory block is large enough to contain `struct s2` (e.g. allocated by `malloc(sizeof(struct s2))`)?

In other words, is it correct (i.e. portable) to reinterpret a memory cell containing a pointer to `struct s1` structure as if it were a pointer to `struct s2`?

(Disclaimer: I am perfectly aware that this is a very weird way to play with pointers, my question is theoretical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, pointers are not required to have the same size or representation.

It means `sizeof (int *)` can be different to `sizeof (double *)` for example.

The only requirements are:

- `void *` , `char *`, `signed char *` and `unsigned char *` have the
  same representation.
- Pointers to structures have the same representation.
- Pointers to unions have the same representation.

Comment: Can you give an example when `sizeof (int*)` differs from `sizeof (double*)`?

Comment: Historically, some (very very old) lisp machines had words of 36 bits and "tagged" addresses: 32 bit for plain address and 4 bits for a data type tag. So a pointer contained information about the type of the pointer, and a cast operation wasn't in general just a copy of bits. I don't know if today there are CPUs with similar architecture.

Comment: @mikithskegg for `int *` and `double *` I don't know but for example Cray PVP systems have 64-bit representation for  `char *` and 32-bit representation for `double *`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. All pointers have the same size and structure. They differ only in "the mind" of compiler.

Comment: This is not true, pointer types are not required to have the same representation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

A pointer is, in its representation, just an integer holding a memory location address of any data type.

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful when abstracting some data. You can have :

```
struct s1
{
  char header[4];
  int  type;
  char data_max[200];
};

struct s1_type1
{
  char header[4];
  int  type;
  char data_of_some_implementation[80];
  char data_of_other_implementation[120];
};
```

And then use it like this

```
struct s1 data;
int nb = read(fd, &data, sizeof(data));
if (nb == sizeof(data))
{
  if (data.type == 1)
  {
    do_something_special((struct s1_type1*)&data);
  }
}
```